# 2009 Ford Focus SE, Vibration returning after replacing Engine Mount

Tags: engine, ford, automatic-transmission, vibration, drivetrain

Like the title says, my car is a '09 Ford Focus SE, with an automatic transmission.

Last year it started developing a vibration. Between two jobs and school, I just didn't have time to get it looked at. It got progressively worse and worse, to the point that it was hard to hold a conversation because of the noise. It failed inspection and I was informed that two of my engine mounts had gone bad (Right hand mount and anti-torque mount underneath.)

I found the time to replace them myself, and it actually completely fixed the vibration issue. The car was running so smoothly that I couldn't even tell the engine was on - No noise, no vibration, nothing.

Over the last few months, the vibration has been slowly returning. It's nowhere near as bad as it was last time, but it's probably best to be proactive with maintenance and repair.

- Is it possible that the left-hand side mount I did not replace is causing the issue?

  - Is it possible/likely the replaced mounts are now damaged and need to be replaced again?
- Is this a symptom of an underlying problem?

  - if so, what are likely problems, and how difficult are they to fix?

Comment: I've heard from a mechanic friend that rocks will sometimes get stuck in the motor mounts on these Focuses. If possible, I'd inspect the mounts for any obstructions in them first and then see if they have too much play in any of them after the debris argument has been dismissed.

Comment: Vibration only when moving? or engine vibration even when parked? Does it get worse with vehicle speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a TSB on this issue and a shield to preven rocks from interfering with mount.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Great find Moab :o)

Comment: Beautiful. What's a TSB and where'd you get this from?

Comment: TSB= Technical Service Bulletin, some are public some are not and have to be sourced through a 3rd party information service.